# selenium test not selecting inner frame

Tags: python, iframe, selenium, selenium-rc

I have a selenium test that I am trying to get up and running but one problem is that it has to select a frame and is failing at it.

the html looks like this

```
<iframe src="#" name="mainframe" id="mainframe" />
```

and the python test uses the command

```
sel.select_frame("mainframe")
```

and when I run the test I get an output like this

> sel.select_frame("mainframe")
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/selenium/selenium/selenium.py", line 901, in select_frame
>       self.do_command("selectFrame", [locator,])
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/selenium/selenium/selenium.py", line 217, in do_command
>       raise Exception, data
>   Exception: ERROR: Element mainframe not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the input I did not verify that the above solution works but the problem was related to the script executing a function before it had logged into the application

Answer (score 2):

Try using the CSS identifier of the iframe...

```
sel.select_frame("css=iframe[id=mainframe]")
```